# Why doesn't Firefox cache my images and CSS

Tags: iis7, iis

I am using IIS7, I have already set up the following. But when I run Firefox it seems not to cache any of my images even with "remember history" set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However when I use Firebug it still points to Firefox not caching images and CSS:

```
public,max-age=604800
Content-Type    text/css
Content-Encoding    gzip
Last-Modified   Mon, 27 Jun 2011 03:53:22 GMT
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Etag    "507968c27d34cc1:0"
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Mon, 27 Jun 2011 13:06:41 GMT
Content-Length  5067
Request Headersview source
Host    www.xx.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept  text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://www.xx.com/
Cookie  __utma=62996397.135679654.1309106351.1309159743.1309164158.8; __utmz=62996397.1309106351.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=62996397
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the request URI for the CSS file?  Firefox will not cache the result when the URI contains a query string (i.e. a ? followed by parameters).

According to the HTTP specifications, a browser should never cache a response from a request containing a query string unless the server explicitly allows it. Unfortunately though, Firefox and IE do not comply to this rule. IE does cache it regardless of a query string but Firefox never caches it regardless of any cache control headers.

Comment: This answer is outdated. The current versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE11 all cache resources with a query string, at least when served with a "Cache-Control: max-age=12345" header.

Comment: So @romkyns, this mean that these browsers now comply to the specifications. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Please, update the answer. It is really outdated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the etag header
2. Use the Cache-Control header to have a large max-age value
3. Set the Expires header to be a far future date

I am unsure how to do this with IIS but if you do the above Firefox should cache your images and any other files you wish to have cached.

Comment: If the same resource is only served from single server (no CDN) then having `etag` does not hurt. In IIS6 etag was changing after each configuration alteration. In IIS7 this is no longer an issue. I have etag on all such servers and all browser caching images/css/js with no problems.

Comment: Hello Jon, I thought the whole idea of setting max-age was that I would not have to set an expires date? I have the max-age set at 7 days. Surely firefox would cache if it saw something was going to be of use for the next 7 days. How do I remove the etag header. Maybe that's what's causing my problem. Can I do that on a per-directory basis?

Comment: It's from a single server IIS7 (Windows Azure).

Comment: @Richard A, I use Apache on Linux so I am unfamiliar with how this is done on IIS. But I use a far future date for `cache-control` and `expires` and have unset `etag` since I've read that it isn't very good and also unnecessary if you use the two methods above. I find this is an effective means for caching in every browser including Firefox which is the browser I do most of my testing on.

Comment: @Richard You better ensure that caching is working for images first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you enabled static content compression in IIS?
2. Apparently (according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420995/iis-7-x-static-compression-not-frequently-hit) IIS may decide not to compress files if they are RARELY accessed. I have not had ANY issues with this point -- even freshly created file worked fine.
3. Use bigger `max-age` value -- 30 days or more (although it should not affect caching THAT much to completely prevent file from being cached).

Comment: I'm setting my cache for 7 days ahead but it doesn't seem to work for even 7 seconds :-( How do I enable static content compression?

Comment: `<system.webServer><urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" /></system.webServer>`

Comment: TBH "static content compression" **should not** affect caching, but _some times_ it does (don't ask why -- I cannot explain). I just having it On for js/css and other static files -- it does the job well.